# Does NAnt and MSBuild use a compiler?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nant

I have been looking around the various `NAnt vs MSBuild` threads here on Stack Overflow and so far I understand they are both Build Tools. They make use of XML to structure how the build takes place. Additionally one is more suited to VS solutions and projects while the other is more of a flexible scripted approach (you can do more with it).

What I am puzzled about is:

> What actually compiles the source, does MSBuild call a compiler? Does NAnt call MSBuild to call a compiler?

Edit:

Will NAnt call MSBuild or compile a C# project via csc directly?

Comment: Although the C# compiler can be invoked as a library, I appreciate that my build tools do it via the well-recognized and visible command-line interface. Both NAnt and MSbuild have switches to turn up their verbosity so you can see exactly what they are doing: calling csc.exe. (BTW-NAnt predates MSBuild.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

csproj file in Visual Studio import `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` which is an MSbuild file which contains the `CoreCompile` target to do the compilation. This target uses the [CSC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5c8athz.aspx) task to do the actual compilation, which itself call csc.exe.

You can find the `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` file in the framework root directory e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\

NAnt has a csc target, so I assume it works in a similar way.

Comment: Ah ok, so csc is the C# compiler which MSBuild calls.

Comment: I've just seen the csc target in the NAnt example:
http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/csc.html

Thanks for your help, cleared it up!